# Find Duplicate Values and Copy all the duplicate rows into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this master data in Sheet 1 (the actual data contains more than 140,000 rows):

| header 1 | header 2 | header 3 | Name | ID Number | header 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 | cell 5 | Ariana | 123 | cell 7 |
| cell 3 | cell 4 | cell 6 | Briana | 124 | cell 8 |
| cell 9 | cell 10 | cell 11 | Charlie | 125 | cell 9 |

I created conditional formatting for duplicate values in ID Number column. I wish to make the VBA copy all duplicate rows into Sheet 2.

For example, I have this new data I'll paste it into the master data (Sheet 1)

| header 1 | header 2 | header 3 | Name | ID Number | header 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 | cell 6 | Briana | 124 | cell 7 |
| cell 9 | cell 10 | cell 11 | Charlie | 125 | cell 8 |
| cell 12 | cell 18 | cell 19 | Dylan | 126 | cell 20 |

It means Briana and Charlie are both duplicate data.

I want VBA to copy the initial row for Briana and Charlie from the master data and also copy the duplicate row so then I can do double-check on the value inside both rows. Note: copy all duplicate values to sheet "Duplicate"

Here is my current code but when I run it there is run-time error
'1004' says "That command cannot be used on multiple selection".

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()

Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Duplicate")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:S" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(2, 1)
    .ClearContents
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When dealing with a large dataset, applying formulas and converting them may result in slow performance.
- Using a `Dictionary` to identify duplicated rows offers a more efficient solution.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub FilterAndCopyDup()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, dupRng As Range, rowRng As Range
    Dim arrData, oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Const KEY_COL = "E" ' Col [ID Number]
    Const COL_CNT = 19 ' Col A to S
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Duplicate")
    ' load data from sheet1
    With oSht1
        Set rngData = .Cells(1, KEY_COL).Resize(.Range(KEY_COL & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    arrData = rngData.Value
    If Not VBA.IsArray(arrData) Then
        MsgBox "No data is on Sheet1.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' load data into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 1) = CStr(arrData(i, 1))
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        Set rowRng = oSht1.Cells(i, 1)
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            If dupRng Is Nothing Then
                Set dupRng = Application.Union(rowRng, objDic(sKey))
            Else
                Set dupRng = Application.Union(dupRng, rowRng, objDic(sKey))
            End If
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = rowRng
        End If
    Next i
    If Not dupRng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print dupRng.Address
       dupRng.EntireRow.Copy oSht2.Range("A2")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

btw, the `helperRng` is on Col U instead of Col T (which is next to the data table).

```vb
With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:S" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)
```

- You can get the same range with a simpler code

```vb
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Columns(rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1)
```

Comment: I've followed your full code and it's giving type mismatch within this line. For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData). Thank you for your help

Comment: How many non-blank cells in Col A? If A1 is the only non-blank cell, `arrData` is not an array. It raises the error. I've added 4 lines for validation.

Comment: I would think that using `Col [ID Number]` to determine the last row # is more reliable.